# Out of stack space in vba when running code for project euler #1

Tags: vba

```
Option Explicit
Sub peuler1()
Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant
y = 0
For x = 1 To 999
    If x Mod 3 = 0 Or x Mod 5 = 0 Then
    y = y + x
    End If
Next x
Call peuler1
End Sub
```

Why is this taking so long?  it doesn't seem to be too convoluted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are in a [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) loop.

Remove `Call peuler1`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your subroutine from within itself. That's going to give you an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because you seem to call function `peuler1` inside its definition, you then keep going recursively until you fill up stack space.

(I don't use visual basic, just a guess)

Comment: where does the call peuler1 go then?  doesn't the end sub close the program?

Comment: yes, and the call is before the `End Sub` statement. So when from outside the scope of that function you call it, it keeps calling itself..

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Option Explicit 
Function peuler1() as integer
   Dim x As integer
   Dim y As integer 
   y = 0 
   For x = 1 To 999 
      If x Mod 3 = 0 Or x Mod 5 = 0 Then y = y + x 
   Next x 
   pueler1=y
End Sub
```

This procedure is a *function*, which means it returns a value (*Subs* do stuff. *Functions* calculate something).  Adding `peuler1=y` at the bottom makes the function return the value of y. The advantage of this is that you can now call this procedure from another procedure.

If you are working on this in the standard MS Office VBA Editor, you can get your answer by typing `debug.print peuler1` in the Immmediate window.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `Call peuler1` outside of the `End Sub`. You're calling `peuler1` when you get to the end of `peuler1`, and never get to the end of it.

Comment: the program is telling me that i can only have comments after the end sub